# IE mobile, windows phone jQuery .css() function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, windows-phone

I have a strange issue. I am using jQuery function : `.css()` to set some width/height and paddings. On iOS mobile, Android it works perfectly, but it doesn't work on Windows phone device.

I don't know why, but the IE doesn't see this additional css wrote in javascript.

Can someone explain me why? And how can I fix it?

Example:

```
var a = $(window).width();
$('.element').css('width',a+'px');
```

or maybe it doesn't count the window width?